# Apache crash on image resize

Tags: php, image, apache, image-resizing

I have created a function which resizes images, I made it to work with `.jpg` images. It works good for `jpeg` images, but when a `.png` image is renamed to `.jpg` and it is uplaoded, then on the resize function apache crashes..

how to fix that problem?

**Functions Used :**

```
imagecreatetruecolor()
imagecreatefromjpeg()
imagecopyresampled()
imagejpeg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `imagecreatefrompng()` if the original image was a PNG image. The `imagecreatefromjpeg()` is only able to open JPEG images, which are stored completely differently from PNGs.

To prevent a crash when an invalid image is received, make sure to check the return value before resizing. (`if (!$imgFromFile) { ... }`).

Comment: what is the : $imgFromFile ? does it is : imagecreatefrompng() or jpeg?

Comment: Either one. You'll have to check the return value from whichever one you call.

Comment: $imgFromFile = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES[tmp_name]); then : if(!$imgFromFile) return false... but apache still crash >.<

Comment: What does the error message say? Are you sure you tried loading a JPEG image? Are you sure it's that line, and have you tried putting that line inside a try block, and catching any exceptions?